# 3.5" drive runs continuously

Tags: drive

I installed Ubuntu on an old XP desktop with cd and 3.5 inch drive. The 3.5 inch drive runs continuously.  I installed the equivalent of device manager can found the drive but could not disable it. Is there an easy way to disable this drive?  I suppose the other option is to open the desktop and disconnect it.  Any ideas that someone not familiar with Linux could understand and follow?

Comment: Are you refering to a 3.5" hard drive or floppy drive?

Answer (score 0):

You said the answer, the hard drive will always work (you can try with any OS on the other drive). Just open the PC and detach it. Some BIOSes may have the option to remove the drive.